# Reference to an Annex is being made to an Appendix

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, appendices

I have been working on a document that has both an Appendix and an Annex.
The problem I am having is that whenever I reference a certain chapter in the Annex, it takes me to the same chapter, but in the Appendice (e.g: hyperref to annex A takes me to appendix A).

This is happening both in the body of the paper, and in the table of contents.
Does anyone have a clue on why this is happening? Maybe I've created the Annex not in the best way, but I have no idea on how to make it in another way.

I'll provide a MWE below:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage[english,portuguese,main=english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,latexsym}
\usepackage{accents}
\usepackage{graphicx, epsfig, eepic,epic,pmgraph,pstricks, graphpap}
\usepackage[top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm, left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{titlepic}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[skins]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareCaptionFont{ninept}{\fontsize{9pt{11pt}\selectfont #1}}
\captionsetup{font=ninept}
\usepackage{multirow}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage[acronym,nomain,nonumberlist]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries
\usepackage{dsfont}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{pgfornament} 
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\newpage
\tableofcontents

\newpage
Go to appendix \ref{appendix:a}. Go to annex \ref{annex:a}.



\begin{appendices}
\appendix
\chapter{Appendix A}\label{appendix:a}
\end{appendices}
% -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\newpage
\renewcommand
\appendixname{Annex}
\renewcommand
\appendixpagename{Annexes} 
\renewcommand
\appendixtocname{Annexes}
\begin{appendices}
\appendix
\chapter{Annex A}\label{annex:a}
\end{appendices}
\end{document}
```

It includes all of the packages I have been using in the paper.
Thank you to anyone who tries to help!

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand your problem, perhaps because I don't use `hyperref`.  The typeset output looks fine to me.

Comment: If you run the code on LaTeX you will see that: if I click on the reference to Annex A it leads me to Appendix A, both in the body of the text and in the Index (table of contents).
Like I mentioned. I recommend running the code, to see what I am talking about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't really think you're using `epsfig` (that only exists for compatibility with 30-year-old documents), `epic`, `eepic`, `pmgraph`, `pstricks`, and `graphpap`.

Don't just add to some friend's preamble: just load the packages you ***really*** use.

In any case, with few exceptions that aren't in the code you post, `hyperref` must be loaded last.

Don't mix settings and package loading: maintenance of the document will be easier.

In the following code I commented out anything that doesn't contribute to the issue.

1. Don't issue `\appendix`, you already have `appendices`.
2. Reset the chapter number and change the internal `hyperref` command `\theHchapter` to get a unique anchor.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
%\usepackage[english,portuguese,main=english]{babel}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,latexsym}
%\usepackage{accents}
%\usepackage{graphicx, epsfig, eepic,epic,pmgraph,pstricks, graphpap}
%\usepackage[top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm, left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm]{geometry}
%\usepackage{fancyhdr}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{titlepic}
%\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage[skins]{tcolorbox}
%\usepackage{hhline}
%\usepackage{caption}
%\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
%\usepackage[acronym,nomain,nonumberlist]{glossaries}
%\usepackage{dsfont}
%\usepackage{setspace}
%\usepackage{bm}
%\usepackage{pgfornament} 
\usepackage{hyperref}

%\pagestyle{fancy}
%\DeclareCaptionFont{ninept}{\fontsize{9pt{11pt}\selectfont #1}}
%\captionsetup{font=ninept}

%\makeglossaries

%\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
%\pagenumbering{roman}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\newpage

Go to appendix \ref{appendix:a}. Go to annex \ref{annex:a}.

\begin{appendices}
\chapter{Appendix A}\label{appendix:a}
\end{appendices}

\newpage

\renewcommand\appendixname{Annex}
\renewcommand\appendixpagename{Annexes} 
\renewcommand\appendixtocname{Annexes}
\renewcommand{\theHchapter}{Annex\thechapter}
\begin{appendices}
\setcounter{chapter}{0}
\chapter{Annex A}\label{annex:a}
\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

Now the link in the TOC will lead to the expected place.

Comment: I included all of the packages in "hopes" that maybe some of them, together, were causing the problem. And yes, surprisingly, I really do need and use them all.
Nevertheless, I worked! Thank you, I really couldn't find a way to make it work.